# Action depending on window size jQuery

Tags: jquery, window, size

I am trying to trigger a slide up/down based on window size, but even when the condition is false (window > 800) it does it anyway. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if ($(window).width() <= 800) {
        $('nav ul').hide();
        $("#navBarMobile").click(function() {
            $("nav ul").slideToggle( "slow" );
        });
    }
    else {
        $('nav ul').show();
    }
})
```

Comment: This works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/K6qkV/1/

Comment: Unfortunately the ul is still toggled when the browser width is bigger than 800 in your fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the window width is relative to the container it is placed in, the innerWidth. If you are attempting to obtain the browsers width and make adjustments after detecting the amount, this would be a viable way:

```
if (window.outerWidth <= 800) {
```

In the fiddle I am providing there is a commented out section. When this section is un-commented, this will also assist in detecting when a resize occurs, which will allow the elements to function more dynamically as well.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/xLUQg/

**Updated:** 
The fiddle without comments : http://jsfiddle.net/t57Qk/

I hope this helps.

Comment: It makes sense but the problem is, when i click the '#navBarMobile' while window <= 800 and resize to window > 800 the 'nav ul' is hidden

Comment: Yes. Unless you uncomment the 2 pieces of code I commented as stated in my Answer. Otherwise, the script will not know that you resized the window.